# Give a html select the css style of the menu used in the jquery UI Autocomplete

Tags: css, jquery-ui, listbox, html-select

I've trying to find a plugin or something that lets me turn a normal html select tag into something more visually attractive, something like the menu that is used in the [autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything that really suits my needs since all of them are designed to work like dropdown lists and what I need is something like a listbox (an html select tag with **size**)
I tried using a [jquery Menu](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/), but I noticed that it always loses focus after one item is selected, plus I'm not really sure if it's going to be a good replacement for a select.

To make a long story short, I need to find way to have a list(like the one shown in the picuture) 
It doesn't matter if it's a select, ul, or whaterver, that uses jquery UI themes and it doesn't matter if it's done using a plugin or CSS.

[image]

Have you ever done or seen anything similar to what I describe ??

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if you find something coz I'm been looking for something like this for a long time :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you check multiselect.js? http://loudev.com/

Comment: Is it possible to have just one listbox and more importantly, can it be used with jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes, you can have a single lisbox. Since the library is built on top of jQuery, there will not be any conflict with jQuery UI

Comment: But `multiSelect()` always adds a second listbox to the right. How can I have only one listbox????